# Changing while loop to accommodate two situations

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a while loop that depends on two separate inputs.  In situation one, the while loop will take the value 1, and in situation two, it should take !cin.eof().  Is there a way I can do this efficiently?  To be more concise:

```
string hello;
cin >> hello;

if(hello == "one")
{
    //make the while loop depend on value 1
}
else if(hello == "two")
{
    //make the while loop depend on value !cin.eof()
}

while(/*depends on above conditional*/)
{}
```

I don't want to do something like:

```
if(hello == "one)
{
     while(1){}
}
else if(hello == "two")
{
     while(!cin.eof){}
}
```

because the while loop essentially does the same thing in each situation.

Comment: By "efficiently", I assume you mean, "with as less code duplication as possible"?

Comment: Have you considered binary arithmetic? Ands and Ors and stuff?

Comment: Have you considered strcmp instead of == ?

Comment: @UdoKlein Yeah, that's the next thing. I had assumed this was merely exemplaric for a more robust approach.

Comment: @UdoKlein: that makes no difference... `std::string` can be compared for equality with a literal and it won't be slower than `strcmp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For readability and in the interest of [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29), I think you should move the contents of your loop into a separate function:

```
void DoSomething() { /* ... */ }

// ...
if(hello == "one)
{
    while(1){ DoSomething(); }
}
else if(hello == "two")
{
    while(!cin.eof){ DoSomething(); }
}
```

It's easier to see that the different `while` loops are doing the same thing but their conditions are different.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use or (`||`) as a condition in the while loop. Set the first condition `if(hello == "one")`. Now you have a while loop that will loop if one of the conditions is `true`.

```
bool value = hello == "one";
while (value || !cin.eof) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
while((hello == "one") || (hello == "two" && !cin.eof)) {
}
```

This code will do what you want, because it checks 'is the variable "one"? If so, keep executing. If it's not, it'll check: Is the variable "two"? If so, it'll check for `cin.eof`.

If it's neither, the loop won't execute. (the `&& 1` in the first condition was omitted, because it's always 'true', equalling and infinite loop)

Edit:

To simplify things, you may want to consider this code (as suggested in the comments):

```
bool HelloIsOne = (strcmp(hello, "one") == 0);
bool HelloIsTwo = (strcmp(hello, "two") == 0);

while(HelloIsOne || HelloIsTwo && !cin.eof) {
}
```

The brackets, which I placed in the previous example are actually unnecessary, because `&&` binds stronger than `||`, but they help the general clarity of the code.

Comment: If you are going to add this to a loop, you might as well do the string comparison upfront and store the value in a `bool` to avoid the cost of testing all characters in the strings multiple times to generate the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11:

```
#include <functional>

auto check = (hello == "one") ? []() bool -> { return 1; } :
                                []() bool -> { return !cin.eof(); };
while(check) {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    switch(hello)
    {
        case 'one':
        {
            for(; 1; );
            {
            // your loop here
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'two':
        {
            for(;!cin.eof; )
            {
            // your other loop here
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << " shouldnt get here unless bad user input" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string hello;
    cin >> hello;
    while(hello=="one"?1:(!cin.eof()))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It checks if the string `hello` is "one" and if it's true, the condition of the `while` is `1`, else it is `!cin.eof()` as you wanted.

Comment: @BobJohn This isn't using anything from C++11, it's just doing "or" in an unnecessarily arcane way.

Comment: What's arcane about that? :D